# How do I scan cards and know when it have been successfully evaluated, without making an API call?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, opencv

So I have coded this:

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import re
import time

vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def getText(frame):
    # TODO Do I really need to convert to PIL from numpy array?
    im = Image.fromarray(frame).convert('LA')
    textAreaImage = im.crop((200, 70, 470, 105))
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(textAreaImage , lang = 'eng')
    newtext = re.sub('[^A-Za-z '',]+', '', text)
    if(newtext != ""):
        print(newtext)


while(True):
    ret, frame = vid.read()

    getText(frame)

    cv2.rectangle(frame,(200,70),(470,430),(0,255,0),1)
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(200,70),(470,105),(255,0,0),1)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This scans and can identify a card perfectly fine theoretically, but when I move the card into place it looks like this

```
Po
Rof
Roofto
Rooftop Storm
Rooftop Storm
Rooftop Storm
Roodkd
Rod
0
De
Rooftop Saorm
Rooftop Storm
Drftop
ds
dd
De
```

This is because the detector throws duds at us. In this case I was scanning a card named "Rooftop Storm"

[image: rooftop-storm]

How do I actually detect when a genuine word have been entered so I can make an API call with the correct name, and not the noice around it? Because if I called an API with every one of this requests, it would sort of be a DOS attack.... Want a smarter way of doing it but can not figure out a way.

Edit: Or possibly make a prediction on if there is words on the sides. Because there is not on playingcards, that would solve my problem

Comment: perhaps assess how much the object moves. while it moves, don't attempt to decode. -- question requires more detail, such as example input data.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Sorry for late response, been a lot at work. But yeah that is not a bad ideea, it would also allow me to limit the ammount of API calls made. Will try it and either come back with a solution or some example input data.